# Javascript: Phone firebase auth: How to put email?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to allow user that logged with phone firebase auth to put his email.

Note: I don't mean I want to login by email. I mean only put the email to the user auth information if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To [set a user's email address](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#set_a_users_email_address) you can do:

> ```
> var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
>
> user.updateEmail("user@example.com").then(function() {
>   // Update successful.
> }).catch(function(error) {
>   // An error happened.
> });
> ```